# Print JSON string in dropdown menu

Tags: php, json

I am getting a problem in generating values of a JSON string into a dropdown menu.I have a JSON API

```
http://service.proventustechnologies.com/api/json?username=demo&token=4ce26206-025d-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66&method=getattributevalues&dimensionId=10
```

When you click it you will see many values like this.

```
{
"response": {
    "id": 10,
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 258,
            "value": "Cameras"
        },
        {
            "id": 2581,
            "value": "GPS Navigation"
        },
        {
            "id": 259,
            "value": "MP3 Players"
        },
        {
            "id": 260,
            "value": "Cell Phone/PDA"
        },
        {
            "id": 6377,
            "value": "Digital Photo Frame"
        },
        {
            "id": 110,
            "value": "Motherboard"
        },
        {
            "id": 108,
            "value": "Desktop/Server"
        },
        {
            "id": 109,
            "value": "Notebook"
        },
        {
            "id": 10738,
            "value": "E-Book Reader"
        }
    ],
    "name": "System Type"
},
"status": "ok"
```

}

I want to print all the values such as Cameras,GPS Navigation in a dropdown menu.Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really get a feel for what your level of knowledge is, but you should load your data in a html select element for example like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<select>';

    $jsonData = file_get_contents($url); 
    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

    foreach($jsonDataObject->response->values as $option){
        echo '<option value=' . $option->id . '>' . $option->value . '</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm using echo here to output html, this depends on how you build html in your application.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question, please mark it by clicking the 'V' on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert json encoded string into PHP variable:

```
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents($your_url);

  $obj = json_decode($json);
  echo $obj->response->id; // prints 10 (based on your sample code)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

hridaynehu,

                 Its very easy to populate the select box using your json array values. Follow below line of code.

```
<?php
     $url = 'http://service.proventustechnologies.com/api/json?username=demo&token=4ce26206-025d-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66&method=getattributevalues&dimensionId=10';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $jsonArray = json_decode($content, true);?> 


<select name="json_populate"><?php 
    foreach($jsonArray->response->values as $jsonValue) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $jsonValue->id; ?>"><?php echo $jsonValue->value; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Please mark it answer if it helps you. Because it may help others too.

With Thanks & Regards,
Sanjoy Dey

Comment: Thanks for your hard work [Sanjay Dey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1085825/sanjay-dey)